# How do I get new user input after already taking in one user input in QLineEdit?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots

I have a program which executes a specific task when some conditions are met.

I want the QLineEdit to work just like input() function of python. I want it so that the program stops for the (new) user's input before moving ahead with the code.

**MainGui.py** *(A small part of/Minimal code for understanding)*

```
From PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QLineEdit,QPushButton,QStackedWidget,QMainWindow,QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType
import sys
import Weather

ui,_ = loadUiType('icons\\Bot.ui')

class MainApp(QMainWindow, ui):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)  #Removes Title bar
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground) #Removes the remaining border
        self.Handle_Text()

    def setTB(self,text):
        OP = self.OutputTB.setText(text)

    def Handle_Text(self):
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.process)

    def process(self):
        sentence = self.lineEdit.text().lower() #user inputs 'weather'

        if "weather" in sentence: #true
            self.setTB("which City ?")
            #Take the userinput for city here
            City = self.lineEdit.text() #stores weather [problem line]
            self.setTB(Weather.weatherreport(City))
        else:
            self.setTB("Enter an actual city please.")
        self.lineEdit.clear()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I wish to do here is that I want the program to Wait after asking 'Which City?' so that the user can enter the city, for example, London, after getting the input the program will store it in the variable called 'City' and then pass that value to 'Weather.weatherreport(City)' [weatherreport is a function taken from another file below]
Currently, the program considers the text that is already present in the LineEdit. I have tried making functions specifically for this second input for the city but the program would skip them and continue ahead.

More clarification(Stepwise):

1. The user enters a string in QlineEdit That contains 'weather' word in it
   For example, 'What is the weather?'
2. The program detects that the given string has weather in it with the help of this line
   'if "weather" in sentence:'
3. Then the program will display a question in the QtextBrowser asking for a city name.
   'self.setTB("which City ?")'
   [(setTB is a function for the QTextBrowser named 'OutputTB']
4. After this, the user would enter the city name in the same LineEdit in which they entered the weather string (from step 1)
5. The new input(input for city name) will then be stored in a variable called 'City' Ex. The user enters London.
6. This variable, City which contains a city name will then be passed to a function from an imported module with this:
   Weather.weatherreport(City)
7. And the temperature of that city will be displayed on the QTextBrowser(named OutputTB)

Step 4 is the part I'm not quite getting right as the lineEdit would keep the input from step 1(What is the weather) and pass that to the weatherreport function. As that is not a city name, the weatherreport function would give me an error.

Weather.py

```
import requests

def weatherreport(City):
    #Url Components 
    BASE_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
    City = City.capitalize()
    API_KEY = "[API Key from OpenWeatherMap]"

    # Joining the Url components to makeup a URL
    # '&units=metrics' converts the temperature from kelvin to celcius
    URL = BASE_URL + "q=" + City + "&appid=" + API_KEY + "&units=metric"

    response = requests.get(URL)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        main = data['main']

        temperature = main['temp']
        humidity = main['humidity']
        pressure = main['pressure']
        report = data['weather']
        
        return("\n" + City.capitalize())
        
        return(f"Temperature: {temperature} degree Celcius")

        return(f"Humidity: {humidity}%"))

        return(f"Atmospheric Pressure: {pressure} hecto Pascals")

        return(f"Weather : {report[0]['description']}")
    else:
        # showing the error message
        return("Error in the HTTP request")
```

Ui Page, TextBrowser is above the LineEdit

[image]

I have seen other questions on SO already but none of them depicts this specific case.

I have seen many answers from @eyllanesc as well. I am using pyqt5.

GitHub link for full project: https://github.com/SaadMansuri3/AVA

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding. Do you want to use the same line edit for both actions, the "command" and the "city", so that the user will type "weather", presses return, then types a city and presses return again it will then go on with processing the city weather?

Comment: Your question is unclear as they already pointed out to you, could you explain better and clarify it as an edition in your post

Comment: yes, @musicamante that is exactly what I am trying to do. However  I have tried to clarify the question more, to the best of my abilities as ellyanesc pointed out.